# oracle - plsql function that will Sorted by characters

Tags: oracle

I need an oracle - plsql function that will Sorted by characters within a word entered and it could be a few characters in the word that they are not one by one .
for example : 
searching for BD characters in the word ABCD then show me all the words with BD as u see BD were not consecutive letters ABCD word and thats my problem.
i need to find every character that the user was type and it will give him the all results.
and in what trigger to use with it there ?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read [ask].

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand the question.  You talk about sorting but I don't see anything that you're sorting by.  Are you saying that you care about the order of characters in the word?  So you wouldn't want to match "DCBA" because it has both B and D but not in the correct order?

Comment: You might want to get familiar with [the INSTR function](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions073.htm#SQLRF00651). Best of luck.

Comment: hi, if for example the user has type "DB" so the sorting will give him all situations with the "DB" like "DCBA","DBA."DABC" thatas what i mean.

Comment: hi, if i take ur example "DCBA" so in my case the user has type "DB" so the sorting will give him all situations with the "DB" like "DCBA","DBA"."DABC" thats what i mean. i hope now that u understand my mind .. the characters doesnt need be suite each other in the word that the user has type. also the user can type also 3 characters like "DAC" and he will also get all the results with those characters and it can be not the same order for example : he can get "DCBA","CAD","ABCD","DACB","ACD". all the results with his type choice .

Answer (score 0):

This solution produces all possible anagrams for given word BASE_WORD and then checks if these anagrams matches with letters in SEARCH_WORD.

You have to create table WORDS like in code section below. Probably solution without table is possible, but I am not sure if I understood you correctly, 
so for start lets try this way.

Be careful, for 9-characters length BASE_WORD you get ~1000000 anagrams, so for longer words it may take some time.

```
-- create below table, this is only needed once:
create table words (word varchar2(20), ok number(1) default 0);  

-- copy, paste and compile my procedure p_words, code at bottom

-- run procedure p_words with parameters BASE_WORD and SEARCH_WORD:
begin p_words('DBCA', 'ACD'); end;
```

You can get all words that matches criteria like here:

```
-- select words using this query:
select word from words where ok=1 order by word

     WORD
     ----
  1  ABCD
  2  ABDC
  3  ACBD
  4  ACD
  5  ACDB
     ...
 27  DBCA
 28  DCA
 29  DCAB
 30  DCBA
```

Procedure code:

```
create or replace procedure p_words(i_base varchar2, i_search varchar2) as 
  v_sql varchar2(4000);
begin
  -- clear previous words
  delete from words;

  -- build all possible anagrams of BASE WORD and insert them into table 
  insert into words (
    select distinct replace(sys_connect_by_path(chr, '/'), '/'), 0
      from (
        select rownum rn, substr(i_base, rownum, 1) as chr 
          from dual connect by level <= length(i_base))
      connect by nocycle rn <> prior rn); 

  -- build condition part for execute immediate
  v_sql := 'update words set ok = 1 where 1=0';

  -- building rest of conditions in loop for each 
  -- possible combination of letters in SEARCH_WORD
  for o in (select * from (
      with input as (select i_search as word from dual),
      l as (select rownum rn, substr(i.word, rownum, 1) as chr 
        from input i connect by level <= length(i.word))
      select level lvl, sys_connect_by_path(chr, '%')||'%' word
        from l connect by nocycle rn <> prior rn)
    where lvl = length(i_search))
  loop
    v_sql := v_sql ||' or word like '''||o.word||'''';
  end loop;

  -- execute update on field words.OK
  execute immediate v_sql;
  commit;

end p_words;
```